# Cannot display characters"Œ œ Š š Ÿ † ‡ • … ‰ € ™" using "UTF-8" and "ISO-8859-1"

Tags: xslt

I'm trying to display these special characters, "Œ œ Š š Ÿ ƒ  – — ‘ ’ ‚ “ ” „ † ‡ • … ‰ € ™" while generating the report. I tried all the encodings like UTF-8, ISO-8859-1 to ISO-8859-10. But none of them worked. Empty boxes are displayed instead of special characters in chrome and nothing was displayed in IE. Below is the piece of code that i was trying to modify in XSLT. 
""

```
<xsl:output method="html" encoding="ISO-8859-9"/>
```

Empty boxes in chrome and no output in IE when tried to open some HTML report

Comment: To solve encoding problems, we need MUCH more information, because things can go wrong at any stage in the processing chain so we need exact details of the data flow. You haven't even told us whether the XSLT transformation was in the browser or on the server. You haven't told us whether the special characters originate in the source document or the stylesheet, or what the encodings of the source document and stylesheet are, etc etc.

Comment: Hey Michael! I am entirely new to this concept. we generally deploy XSLT in our server(Matrix Navigator). Data generated in the report is taken from our application and users input the data required. So special characters do not originate in the source document itself, but are taken from the UI.

Comment: The basic methodology is to look carefully at the end-to-end data flow and examine the data that's being passed step by step to see at what point the encoding first becomes incorrect. Sometimes it's before the XSLT transformation, sometimes it's after. Somewhere in your data flow you will find that the writer of a data stream is assuming one encoding and the consumer of that stream is assuming a different encoding.